# What are these doorstops called?

Tags: doors, door-frame

I've encountered these doorstops in Japan, but I can't figure out what to call them. They are on interior doors.

They aren't on the hinges, so they aren't hinge-pin. They are mounted on the door *frame* - but searching "frame mounted" isn't consistent.

I also thought "door jamb stop" might yield results, and it does, but I still don't know what I should call it if I were to talk to someone about them.

So what's the name of these?

[image]
[image]
[image: image description]

Comment: that looks like something that would get ripped out because of the force exerted on the door stop when the door is flung open

Comment: As @jsotola says, the force on one of these would be massive. Moment = force x lever arm, and the lever arm (horizontal distance from the hinge) is tiny compared to the lever arm of the door's mass. Therefore to get the same moment (to stop the door) the force will be massive compared to a doorstop near the moving edge of the door.

Comment: They might leave an impression on the door with kids opening doors but then it’s off the floor

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 yeah, no kids and puppies that eat the rubber ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

combined doorstop

no idea why it is called that

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Combined-Doorstop_120756102.html?spm=a2700.7724857.main07.63.6fab1fe1FMcc4F